# flutter: custom shape as text background

Tags: flutter, shapes

I need to achieve this in flutter:

[image]

I tried making a `Row` and setting a background to the `Text` to handle the ractangle, then a `ClipPath` to make the triangle. The problem with this is that the edge is not precise (you can see a thin line between the rectangle and the triangle in the image below), also the `ClipPath` has fixed size so if I want to change the text size at some point I'll have to fine-tune the triangle again.

[image]

here's my code:

```
class TriangleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 3, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(TriangleClipper oldClipper) => false;
}

Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Text(
                "a label",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: TriangleClipper(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              height: 23,
              width: 20,
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

I though using `double.infinity` instead of fixed size in `ClipPath`'s child would solve it but doing that makes the triangle disappear (probably it becomes too big that I can't see it or goes behind something).

What is the correct way to approache this problem? I guess I could draw the trapezoid using a `ClipPath`, but how to make it so the width of it adapts to the lenght of the `Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is like so.

```
class TriangleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final w = size.width;
    final h = size.height;
    final triangleWidth = 10;

    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, h);
    path.lineTo(w, h);
    path.lineTo(w - triangleWidth, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(TriangleClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

and use it like so.

```
ClipPath(
    clipper: TriangleClipper(),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 14, 4),   // 4 + triangleWidth for right padding
      color: Colors.orange,
      child: Text('A label'),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

child: CustomPaint(
  size: Size(WIDTH,(WIDTH*0.625).toDouble()), //You can Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
  painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
),


class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    

  Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    paint_0.shader = ui.Gradient.linear(Offset(size.width*0.29,size.height*0.28),Offset(size.width*0.29,size.height*0.28),[Color(0xff7c1010),Color(0xffffffff)],[0.00,1.00]); 
         
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width*0.2937500,size.height*0.2780000);

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
  

  Paint paint_1 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
     
         
    Path path_1 = Path();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.3750000,size.height*0.4000000);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.5000000,size.height*0.4000000);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.5375000,size.height*0.5000000);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.3750000,size.height*0.5000000);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.3750000,size.height*0.4000000);
    path_1.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_1, paint_1);
  
    
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

[image]

**You can try it by yourself: https://shapemaker.web.app/#/**

Comment: doesn't that use a fixed width? I need to size the shape according to label lenght

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried this solution and it worked fine`

// put this is in home_page

Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomPaint(
                  size: Size(80, 60),
                  painter: MyPainter1(),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 60,
                       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'A label',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: AppFontsSizeManager.s20.sp,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),),

// This is the Class

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jeras/config/colors_file.dart';

class MyPainter1 extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint() ..color = AppColors.grey4..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final w = size.width;
    final h = size.height;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(w / 10, h / 3); // 5
    path.lineTo(w, h / 3); // 1
    path.lineTo(w, h); // 2
    path.lineTo(w / 10, h); // 3
    path.lineTo(0, h / 1.5); // 4

    canvas.drawPath(
      path,
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}`
```